# Moving Average with FactTable (dateID) & DateDIM PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have created a *'3-days moving average'*-measure in power BI.
It all works fine as long as I have a DateColumn in my FactTable and use that as the axis.

Is there a way to re-write my code in DATESINPERIOD so that the measure gets the date from my DateDIM-table via DateID??
maybe with *Lookupvalue* or *Related*?

[FactTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnvRv.png)

```
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(FactTable;[Average Sales per day])/3;
        DATESINPERIOD(
            FactTable[Date];
        LASTDATE(FactTable[Date]);
        -3;
        DAY
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.
You will need to rename fields and tables to match the one in your model.

```
CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales SalesOrderHeader'[SubTotal]),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
            'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ('Calendar'[Date]) 
            && 'Calendar'[Date] > ( MAX('Calendar'[Date])-3)
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm not allows to refer "DateTo" in the VAR "DateFrom" Apparently.
Are your suggestion a Measure?

Comment: My bad, you can use variables inside variables, but not in this case. Also, the formula will work without variables. I will edit the answer.